# How to pass an array in a variable for :collection in form for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

Here is a simple_form code in _form.html.erb.

```
  <%= f.input :start_time, :label => "Start Time：", :collection => @time_slot %>
```

@time_slot is a variable defined in the controller. It is an array and looks like:

```
 @time_slot = ['00:30 AM','01:00 AM','01:30 AM','02:00 AM','02:30 AM','03:00 AM' ,'03:30 AM','04:00 AM','04:30 AM']
```

The problem is that the rendered view does not have the dropdown menu with the predefined time slots listed. Instead it only shows a text box.

How to show the drop down time slots instead of a text box? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: input was deprecated in v2.3.8, so if you're using Rails3 you should probably not be using input. Instead, use the proper form helpers, for a drop-down box (or select tag) you'd want:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

but if you must - you can probably pass the input-type eg `:type => :select` but I've never tried that and it may not work.

Comment: :type => :select did not work. Tried :as => :select and not work as well. I can move the @time_slot into the view and define it as :collection => [....] for the field. However the view code would look bulky and ugly. That's why I would like to define it in the controller and re-use it in views. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The problem is that the @time_slot has to be defined in the methods in controller, such as new, edit, in order to be passed into the view. The value of the one defined at the top of the controller was not passed into the view. Does it make sense?

Comment: The problem was the value of @time_slot was not passed into the view. What I did was to define a set_time_slot method in controller to return the time_slot array and put it in helper_method to make it available to views. And also to put it for before_filter to run set_time_slot before anything else in the controller. Here is a post:  http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=21354

Comment: `#input` is still a valid method for `simple_form`, which he mentions he was using :)

Comment: @FedericoBuiles ah. Thanks - I missed that :)

Comment: The problem was solved by define a method in controller to return the time slot array and call the method in view. Remember to declare the method with helper_method in controller so the view can call it.

Comment: Hi again @user938363  - glad you got a solution. You should put it as a proper "answer" though (not just a comment) - it's allowed to answer your own questions, and even to select it as the chosen answer (with the tick next to it). It lets people, that have the same problem in future, to find your question and know that it was solved. :)